# Lstlisting - define other color for pre-postfix names

Tags: listings

I am using the listings package and try to define my own XML style. It looks like this:

```
\lstdefinestyle{webxml}{%
language=XML,
tagstyle=\color{purple},
keywordstyle=[1]{\color{red}},
keywordstyle=[2]{\color{purple}},
morekeywords=[1]{name},
}
```

Now I stuck with a problem:

```
<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
<name>peer</name>
```

The name value in the first line occurs red. Thats correct. But the second "tag" also appears in red. how can i change the color of the "name" tag back to purple? Is there a way to add additional tags? compared to morestring or morekeyword?

[image]

Thanks for the help.

Here is also an MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{listings, xcolor}

\lstdefinestyle{webxml}{%
language=XML,
tagstyle=\color{purple},
keywordstyle=[1]{\color{red}},
keywordstyle=[2]{\color{purple}},
morekeywords=[1]{value, name},
keywords=[2]{<name>} %???
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=webxml]
<property name="eclipselink-ddl-generation" value="create tables" />
<name>peer</name>
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```